# Using @ref inside for loop to get element reference

Tags: javascript, c#, .net-core, blazor

Im trying to get the position of same object in different places, where ,with a javascript function, I should get different top positions but thats not the scenario. The script code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.ShowAlert = function myFunction(element) {   
    console.log("Hello World.");
    alert(element.offsetTop);
   }
</script>
```

The Index.razor code:

```
@inject IJSRuntime jsRuntime

<div>
    @for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        <div @onclick="MemberFunction" @ref="memberRef">Click Here</div>
    }

</div>

@code {

    private ElementReference memberRef;
    void MemberFunction()
    {
        jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<object>("ShowAlert", memberRef);
    }
}
```

As you can see here Im doing a `for` in the same div, where he goes down the line. What I want from this is for every `div` posted it should give me a different value of `offsetTop`, because he goes down the line one by one. How can I manage this problem?

For a better understanding here you have a demo https://blazorfiddle.com/s/4g57o82k . As you can see in the demo the value for each **Click Here** is the same.

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get position/offset of element relative to a parent container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11634770/get-position-offset-of-element-relative-to-a-parent-container)

Comment: same element is passed in memberRef no matter on which div you are clicking

Comment: @ControlAltDel let me have a check.

Comment: @BabarBilal what you suggest to do?

Comment: @ControlAltDel I don't think so, I having an issue with the same value for same object in different positions, not having with getting the element position relative to a parent.

Comment: I happened across this question and found a way to pass the index: https://blazorfiddle.com/s/50nwz2is

Comment: @LOLJovem I opened an [issue](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/14700) that references this question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Edit:

I believe that this is a bug, so I created an [issue](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/14700). If it's not an issue or it get fixed, I will update here.

Looking at the [docs about lambda expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components?view=aspnetcore-3.0#lambda-expressions)

> Do not use the loop variable (`i`) in a `for` loop directly in a lambda expression. Otherwise the same variable is used by all lambda expressions causing `i`'s value to be the same in all lambdas. Always capture its value in a local variable (`buttonNumber` in the preceding example) and then use it.

So looking at the issue and the [answer it was given](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/14700#issuecomment-538127829) I tweak it a little and manage to make it work.

You need to define a new varible inside the `for` to hold the value of `i`.

```
@inject IJSRuntime jsRuntime

<div>
    @for(var i = 0; i < memberRef.Count(); i++)
    {
        var i2 = i;
        <div @onclick="() => MemberFunction(i2)" @ref="memberRef[i2]">Click Here</div>
    }
</div>

@code {

    private ElementReference[] memberRef { get; set; } = new ElementReference[11];
    void MemberFunction(int i)
    {
        jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<object>("ShowAlert", memberRef[i]);
    }

}
```

Here is a working [fiddle](https://blazorfiddle.com/s/1cw32fbp).

Comment: For some reason Im not able to test, some errors occurring in this line:`<div class="memberBox" id="member" @onclick="() => MemberFunction(i)" @ref="memberRef[i]">`

Comment: @LOLJovem the error is that it doesnt find `i`. I'm trying to solve that too, just a sec

Comment: Ok no problem. Go ahead!

Comment: @LOLJovem boy... this is going to be hard. I edited the asnwer and the code works, but it it also only sends the last element of the array. I'm trying to find out why but no clue so far

Comment: I believe and understand, I appreciate all the work that you are doing. And im not worry about the time or anything that could go wrong. Have your time! Good luck!

Comment: Thank you one more time! Appreciate all the work you did here! Thank you so much!

Comment: Just found this - very useful - thanks so much for fiddle - I now know about blazorfiddle too! I  just had to delete this line
 using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Builder;
 to get the latest version of the fiddle to work.