# Add @ref to a Blazor component in a loop

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-compiler

How to add a `@ref` to Blazor components inside a loop?

```
@for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    <MyComponent @ref="???"/> // I want to add this component to the list
}

@code
{
    List<MyComponent> components = new List<MyComponent>();
}
```

Answer (score 28):

My solution is as follows:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{ 
    <MyComponent @ref="ComponentRef" />
}

@code {
    List<MyComponent> ComponentRefs = new List<MyComponent>();
    MyComponent ComponentRef {
        set { ComponentRefs.Add(value); }
    }
}
```

[Explanation](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/13358#issuecomment-582057368)

Comment: Yes, this works too. Check the obj folder and find MyComponent.razor.g.s.You will see `__value` in the generated code there.

Comment: The problem with this is that there is no process to remove items from the ComponentsRefs list if the contents of the for loop change.

Comment: I'm still looking for a solution for this, especially variable length arrays/lists. For fixed size this works: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58205090/using-ref-inside-for-loop-to-get-element-reference. Ironically, I had the same idea but i deem it perverse (or Blazor that is). @ref=item[i] does behave like a lambda and will not work unless capturing `i` locally, but using a single Property and misusing the setter works. OMG! The real problem is, where/when are the refs ACTUALLY assigned. IDK of any method to access this. `BuildRenderTree` executes more often. `OnRenderAsync` also.

Comment: @ChristopherEdwards: What do you mean "loop changed"?

Answer (score 4):

The way that Blazor compiler works now, you can inject `C#`code on `@ref` attribute. You can use it for adding the components to a list.

```
@for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    <MyComponent @ref="components.Add((MyComponent)__value);//" />
}

@code
{
    List<MyComponent> components = new List<MyComponent>();
}
```

Comment: Where does this __value come from? 
"The name '__value' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: Could it be that this somehow was deprecated with a newer version? I can't even find `__value` in the razor.g.cs file mentioned in another comment. 

But all in all I'd rather choose not to use this anyway even if I'd find out how. It uses the generated code an is even more subject to change. So I really don't want to rely on this solution

Comment: answer seems to be completely incorrect. I get a compiler error that @ref must be a property or variable assignment

Comment: As of writing this comment, this approach does not work.

Comment: @Lucas: Did you try this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/60083369/109941

Answer (score 4):

As the above did not work I found one simple solution. [Add the component to an internal list on the ref setter.](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/13358#issuecomment-582057368) You can then reference the component via the index.

Example:

```
private List<MyComponent> components = new List<MyComponent>>();

        public MyComponent MyComponentRef
        {
            get
            {
                return null;
            }
            set
            {
                components .Add(value);
            }
        }
```